# RegOpenKeyEx Not finding an existing value

Tags: c++, registry

I am checking to see if the value "XXS" exists in the run registry

```
if (RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, L"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run\\XXS", 0, KEY_READ | KEY_WOW64_64KEY, &hkey) == ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)
{
        std::cout << "KEY NOT FOUND";
        LONG createStatus = RegCreateKey(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, L"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", &hkey); //Creates a key       
        LONG status = RegSetValueEx(hkey, L"XXS", 0, REG_SZ, (LPBYTE)path, (size + 1) * sizeof(WCHAR));
}
```

I am not sure why this is happening and if I am using this function right. The key does exist but it says it does not. The program is 64 bit running on 64 bit pc

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue here is that you do not differentiate between keys and values.

> Registry keys are container objects similar to folders. Registry values are non-container objects similar to files. Keys may contain values and subkeys.

So you basically need to open/create a key and then handle the values in it.

In your case, i'd try something like this (but be aware, from the top of my head, not tested):

```
#define HKLM_BASE L"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run"
HKEY  hKey;
wchar_t buf[256] = { 0 };

LONG  regError = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,HKLM_BASE,0, KEY_WOW64_64KEY | KEY_ALL_ACCESS,&hKey);
if (regError == ERROR_SUCCESS)
{
    DWORD dwDataSize = sizeof(buf);
    regError   = RegQueryValueEx(hKey,L"XXS", NULL, NULL,(LPBYTE)&buf,&dwDataSize);
    if ((regError != ERROR_SUCCESS) )
    {
        wchar_t *path  =L"your value";
        if (ERROR_SUCCESS != RegSetValueEx(hKey,L"XXS",NULL,REG_SZ,((const BYTE*)&path),wcslen (path)))
        {
            /* handle error */
        }
    } else {
     /* current value in buf */
    }
    RegFlushKey( hKey );
    RegCloseKey( hKey );
} else {
    /* handle error */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to stack overflow! While typing this I see Morphine was just a little bit quicker. But he forgot to explain most of the the changes he made. So here are my 2 cents. The example of Morphine  is fine , I won't provide another one.

I think XXS is a value (since you create a value, not a key, if it does not exist). This means you need to check if the value exist, right after you open the registry key. I also advise you to check on any error returning from the function RegOpenKeyEx, not only the ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND error.

Another thing I recommend is using RegCreateKeyEx instead of RegCreateKey, this since the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regcreatekeya) says the following:

> Note  This function is provided only for compatibility with 16-bit
> versions of Windows. Applications should use the RegCreateKeyEx
> function. However, applications that back up or restore system state
> including system files and registry hives should use the Volume Shadow
> Copy Service instead of the registry functions.

Last but not least, don't forget to [close the keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regclosekey) once you do not need them anymore. You don't have to close values.

Comment: Thanks for the extended explanation! yep, i should have added more context :)